# Remember login with OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, authentication, omniauth

Is there an easy way to implement "remember me" functionality with OmniAuth? I'm using Facebook, Identity and LinkedIn, and I'm looking for a way to keep the user logged in to my site across sessions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475726/devise-and-omniauth-remembering-oauth

Answer (score 0):

Basically you set another cookie on the client which persists the userid.  Then use that userid to sign the user in (or at least recognise them) on subsequent visits.  Remember Omniauth just does authentication, not the session management stuff so you need to do this outside Omniauth.

Look at the answer by gareth-simpson to this question: [Implementation of "Remember me" in a Rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438/implementation-of-remember-me-in-a-rails-application)