# Heroku app on new deployment signs out all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, omniauth-facebook

we have a web app built on rails platform and deployed using heroku. Whenever there is a new deployment, users are logged out. Is there a way to keep users logged in after the deployment??

App uses facebook login for the users to login.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this in your `application controller`

```
def current_user
  if cookies[:remember_token].present?
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
end
```

Comment: What is remember_token??

Comment: it's  provide by devise http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable

Comment: The app uses 'omniauth-facebook' for authentication not devise. How can I achieve that without devise??

Comment: @rAzOr have you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497231/remember-login-with-omniauth  I think this is what you are looking

Comment: No. The app doesn't have "remember me" problem. Am using session_id for remember me. Issue is, the user is logged out when new changes are deployed to heroku which is done using `git push app_name master`. Is it because, heroku server restarts after the deployment??

Comment: @rAzOr what you have written inside current_user method , could you share with me

Comment: current_user is a single line code. It has `@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]` in it.

Comment: @rAzOr You storing your sessions in the database? If Yes then don't reset session as it will clear the database also if not then I think you need to generate a databse using this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588241/rails-sessions-current-practices).

Comment: No, Not storing the sessions in the database. Can I know why the users are logged out, after the deployment??

Comment: Is it because, heroku server restarts after the deployment??

Comment: I don't know more about it , but yes it could be one reason it might possible it remove all tmp file and clear cache

Comment: Could this problem be because of  [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)